# Java Helper Class - Different forms of syntax

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am new to java, and I'm learning from lynda.com.

In the tutorial videos on lynda, they write:

```
char 'a1' = a;
System.out.print(Character.toUpperCase(a1));
```

However when I try to write this on IntelliJ IDEA the following code must be written:

```
char 'a1' = a;
System.out.print(java.lang.Character.toUpperCase(a1));
```

When trying to write the same code, why do I need to write java.lang.Character (in the longer form) rather than Character?

I have the same problem when trying to use the other helper class, for example:

```
double d = 124.5;
```

Lynda website code: `byte bS = Double.byteValue(d);`

My code:            `byte bS = Double.valueOf(d).byteValue;`

How can I fix this?

Comment: did you import java.lang.Character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import the class before using it. Try adding `import java.lang.Character;` at the top. Then you will be able to use it like `System.out.print(Character.toUpperCase(a1));`

And, `byteValue()` is not declared as static in `Double.java`. So, we can call that function only on a variable. For example,

```
double d = 124.5;
Double D = d;  // or Double D = 124.5;
byte bS = D.byteValue();
```

or just

```
double d = 124.5;
byte bS = Double.valueOf(d).byteValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
char a1 = 'a';
```

not `char 'a1' = a;`

and

```
 byte bS = Double.valueOf(d).byteValue();
```

(note the parentheses at the end of byteValue)

Both of the errors were syntax related. I'm not sure what lynda.com said but those corrections should fix the issues.

And for those of you who say that you have to add an import for Character, that doesn't seem to be necessary. I'm testing it in IntelliJ right now.

Good luck!